# Find all pairs (x, y) of real numbers such that $16^{x^2+y} + 16^{x+y^2}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all pairs (x, y) of real numbers such that

$$16^{x^2+y} + 16^{x+y^2}=1$$

Comment: This is hard to parse.  Do you mean $16(x^2+y)+16(x+y^2)=1$?

Comment: yes 16 is the base and the others are the exponents

Comment: That is not what I wrote.  so you mean $16^{x^2+y}+16^{x+y^2}=1$

Comment: yeah the same....

Comment: This is hardly a problem about number theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very nice problem!

By application of  inequality $a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab}$ we have
$$16^{x^2+y}+16^{x+y^2}\ge 2\sqrt{16^{x^2+y}\cdot 16^{x+y^2}}=2\cdot 4^{x^2+x+y^2+y}$$
Since $t^2+t\ge-\frac{1}{4}$ holds for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$16^{x^2+y}+16^{x+y^2}\ge2\cdot 4^{x^2+x+y^2+y}\ge 2\cdot 4^{-\frac{1}{2}}=1$$
with equality only in case $x=y=-\frac{1}{2}$, so this is the only solution.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$ we also have $x=(2i + 1)/2$, $y=( - 2i + 1)/2$ and vice versa. Then $x+y^2=x^2+y=-1/4$.

Comment: thanks for the appreciation