# 3 variable equation

Tags: systems-of-equations

I found this question on a math contest but I could not solve it and also could not find the solutions. If anyone could help:
$$ 27^{3x^2+2y} + 27^{3y^2+2z}+27^{3z^2+2x} = 1$$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: __Hint:__ [Modify this similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808158/find-all-pairs-x-y-of-real-numbers-such-that-16x2y-16xy2-1). If you're stuck, show your work. $\min (3x^2 + 2x) = - 1/3$, so the result follows.